# Inserting text with formatting in invitation body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to automate Outlook invites. The code is working until I arrive to the body. I need something more elaborate than just plaintext. I can't find the .HTMLBody property/the compiler doesn't recognize it: Run-time Error '438'.

Is there any other way of inserting text with format in my invite body?

The code works when using .body:

```
Sub Invite_Merge(meeting_date As Date, meeting_time As Double,         
        meeting_duration As Integer, client_email As String, meeting_subject As String,
        meeting_location As String, client_name As String, meeting_body As String,
        meeting_sender As String)


    Dim O As Outlook.Application
    Set O = New Outlook.Application

    Dim OAPT As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set OAPT = O.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    OAPT.MeetingStatus = olMeeting

    Dim meeting_start
    meeting_start = DateValue(meeting_date) + meeting_time

    With OAPT

        .Recipients.Add (client_email)
        .Subject = meeting_subject
        .Start = meeting_start
        .Duration = meeting_duration
        .Location = meeting_location
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"
        .Display
        '.Send

    End With

End Sub


Sub Send_Invites()

    row_number = 2

    Do
    DoEvents

    row_number = row_number + 1
    If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number)) = False Then

        Call Invite_Merge(Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("E" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("F" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("G" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("H" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("A" & "1"))

    End If
    Loop Until row_number = 100

End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=3&messageid=31711

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? What is it?

Comment: The error I receive is: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. When I click on debug it stops on the .HTMLBody line, (I am using Excel 2013

Comment: `AppointmentItem`s do not have an Html body. You need to drop the Html tags and output to `Body` which is the text body.

Comment: Hmmm Thanks Tony, will there be any alternative to include text with format with .body? I have seen that Tim is pointing C# as a solution maybe?

Comment: See repost:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300231/how-to-include-formatted-text-in-the-body-of-an-outlook-invite-from-a-macro-in-e/52303460#