# How to include formatted text in the body of an Outlook invite from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I would like to insert text with format (links, bold, highlighted...) in an Outlook invite using Excel VBA.

I have a program that send invites from Excel. The body contains plain text. I am using .body but I am afraid I will have to use a different approach (.HTMLBody doesn't work for invites and RTFbody seems to be over complicated from what I have read).

I have body templates in Word, in Outlook as quick parts, in the clipboard and some other places.

Code:

```
Sub Invite_Merge(meeting_date As Date, meeting_time As Double,         
    meeting_duration As Integer, client_email As String, meeting_subject As String,
    meeting_location As String, client_name As String, meeting_body As String,
    meeting_sender As String)


Dim O As Outlook.Application
Set O = New Outlook.Application

Dim OAPT As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set OAPT = O.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
OAPT.MeetingStatus = olMeeting

Dim meeting_start
meeting_start = DateValue(meeting_date) + meeting_time

With OAPT

    .Recipients.Add (client_email)
    .Subject = meeting_subject
    .Start = meeting_start
    .Duration = meeting_duration
    .Location = meeting_location
    '.body = here is where I have trouble, the property body only allows me to insert plaintext, .HTMLBody is not a AppointmentsItem property and I have not found an example code on how to use convert a formatted text (with links, bold, different fonts...) into a compatible .RTFBody byte array
    .Display
    '.Send

End With

End Sub


Sub Send_Invites()

row_number = 2

Do
DoEvents

row_number = row_number + 1
If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number)) = False Then

    Call Invite_Merge(Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("E" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("F" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("G" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("H" & row_number), Sheet1.Range("A" & "1"))

End If
Loop Until row_number = 100

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by `.HTMLBody doesn't work for invites` ?

Comment: Instead of posting a new question, maybe try following up on your previouis one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52281033/how-to-enable-htmlbody-on-excel-vba   I was not proposing you use C# - that language did happen to be in the link I posted but this is do-able in VBA.

Comment: Post the code you've written and state explicitly what goes wrong when you try to make your desired changes. Otherwise, you're asking a simple "Yes/No" question.

Comment: Thank you for your answers: Marcucciboy2: AppointmentItems doesn't have the .HTMLBody property. TimWilliams could you show me a code example on how to do so? Sorry for posting a new question Tim, I am new to this forum, I checked the link you shared and tried a few things proposed in it, but  unfortunately I haven't been able to make it work. FreeMan I will edit my question and add the code then, thanks again for your contributions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub SetApptWithHTMLContent()

    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application, appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim m As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim rtf() As Byte

    Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
    Set m = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set appt = olapp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    appt.Subject = "Meeting request"
    '...set other appointment properties
    appt.Display
    'put the HTML into the mail item, then copy and paste to appt
    m.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    m.HTMLBody = Range("A1").Value 'sample HTML stored in a cell
    m.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy
    appt.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Paste
    m.Close False 'don't save...

End Sub
```

Sample HTML:

```html
  <h1>Title Here</H1>
 <span style='background-color: #ffff00'>Table of stuff:</span><br>
 <table>
 <tr>
  <td style='background-color: #ff9900'>One</td>
  <td>Two</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Three</td>
  <td>Four</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Final appointment body:

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly!!!!! Thank you very much Tim!!! Is there any place where I could upload the excel file with the macro for others to download and use? I think many people could find it useful :)

Comment: There's no place here for that.  You can put it somewhere like box/dropbox/etc and post a public URL in a comment, but people (including me) typically very wary about downloading macro-enabled files.

Comment: Yeah, you have a point... and Tim, is there any way I could compensate you for your help?? You can't imagine how useful your help has been :D

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but no need for that - was an interesting challenge for me to figure out and now I have a solution stored here on SO if I ever need one ;-)

Comment: All right then :D thank you very much for your help, I will always be grateful for this :) best wishes and have a nice day!

Comment: You probably would like to add `m.Delete` after `m.Close` if you don't want to leave email in **Drafts** folder.