# Save Outlook appointment created from a template to non default calendar

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I open a Outlook Meeting template and want to associate the appointment created to a non default calendar in Outlook. The attached code saves to the default calendar.

```
Sub Whatever()
Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Dim oApt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim myTemplate As Object
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim nsOther As Outlook.Recipient

Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim template As String

template = "C:\Users\Some User\Meeting.oft"
Set myTemplate = olApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(template)
myTemplate.Recipients.Add ("someuser@contoso.com")
myTemplate.Start = "16/04/2019 10:30"
myTemplate.Display
myTemplate.Send

End Sub
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526145/excel-vba-create-meeting-in-non-default-calendar) is similar but saves a new meeting, not created from a template, to a non default calendar.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300231/how-to-include-formatted-text-in-the-body-of-an-outlook-invite-from-a-macro-in-e) approach stores the html in an Excel cell.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.CreateItemFromTemplate` function takes a second (optional) parameter - `MAPIFolder` where the appointment must be created.

Your script must initialize the `oFolder` variable and pass it to `CreateItemFromTemplate`.